# How to create a draggable NSButton in Swift?

Tags: macos, swift, draggable

I need help finding the starting point: I want to programmatically create a NSButton as a draggable object in Swift. Do I need to subclass NSButton? Do I need a drag handler? There are a few tutorials on this topic, but they're all for iOS and I'm not safe enough to translate that to OS X. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Simple, make a subclass of your button which you want to be draggable . something like this 
@interface CustomButtonSpecial : UIButton  . (you got my meaning, you can take the equivalent in swift i.e UIGestureRecognizerDelegate.

and then use UILongPressGestureRecognizer , add it to your custom button and implement your logic then, what you want this custom buttom to do.